# How to catch click event is finished using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('.test').one('click', function (e) {
    var $wrapper = $(e.target).parents('.wrapper');
    $wrapper.addClass('disable-highlight');

    e.preventDefault();

    $wrapper.removeClass('disable-highlight');
});
```

css

```
.disable-highlight {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

I want to disable highlighting function when click .test button, but the above code, it removes disable-highlight class before click event has done.

so still the highlighting is showing. I think I can use timeout.. but is there any better and cleaner way?

Comment: Hi, first of all try to change .one with .on

Comment: instead of click use mouseup and mousedown --> the click end on mousup

Comment: @Stimart -- [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is also a valid method.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do: do you only want to disable highlight when the mouse is pressed on the button, or do you want to alternate between enabling and disabling highlights (kind of like a toggle, you can turn it on and off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in this way:
Add to you `test` tag

```
onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()"
```

and then:

```
function mouseDown() {
   //while click
}

function mouseUp() {
   //after click
}
```